# Remove time zone offset from date in C#.Net

Tags: c#

i am getting data in xml format which contains below fields 
Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)

The value of ActivatedDate=Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)

i want to get the date and time from the ActivatedDate and compare with today's date  and find the difference in time span(hour) of both the dates .

For ex: (Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28 - 22nd Feb  2016).Hour
I want to find the difference between two dates with respect to hours .

Please help me on this.

Comment: What does the incoming format look like when the day-of-month is a single digit?  Are the character positions constant?  Let me add, this is a real pet peeve of mine, and I'm sure not under your control: XML *has* a standard date-time format that is readily parsed.  And this ain't it.

Comment: <serviceItemAttribute name="ActivatedDate">Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)</serviceItemAttribute>

Comment: Please look into the <serviceItemAttribute name="ActivatedDate">Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)</serviceItemAttribute>

Comment: I want to parse ActivatedDate and  substract from current date. Both the dates are present on same time zone. Please help

Comment: If you use string _activatedDate = ActivatedDate.SubString(0, ActivatedDate.IndexOf("GMT")-1) as the date value with my solution, does this not solve the problem you were asking? Please provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you need to parse the ActivatedDate from a string:

```
string activatedDate = "Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28";
DateTime activeDate = DateTime.Parse(activatedDate);
TimeSpan timeDifference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(activeDate);
double hoursDifference = timeDifference.TotalHours;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  My activatedDate  is coming like ="Sat Feb 13 2016 01:59:28 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)" .Do i need to remove "GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)" from the activated date before parsing . while parsing do i need to mention the format of the date ??

Comment: I would remove the GMT yes, you maybe able to process the +1100 with DateTimeOffset Class though, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654(v=vs.110).aspx